# read json from localhost in Android

Tags: android, json, android-listview, getjson

I want to read a JSON file from my local host but an error occurs. I don't know what is wrong.

JSONParser:

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {
    }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

UpdateFromSite:

```
public class UpdateFromSite extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    TextView name;
    TextView description;
    TextView price;
    Button Btngetdata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newItemlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //URL to get JSON Array

    private static String url = "http://localhost/json/newItem.json";
    //JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_ITEM = "NewItem";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    JSONArray NewItem = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.updateapp);
        newItemlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //check internet connection
                Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
                ConnectionDetector cd;
                cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
                isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();

                if (isInternetPresent) {
                    new JSONParse().execute();  }

                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You don't have internet connection.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                     }
                     }
        });
    }



    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


            name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameNewItem);
            description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.descriptionNewItem);
            price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.priceNewItem);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UpdateFromSite.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                return json;
            }   catch (Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"network problem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            }

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                NewItem = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ITEM);
                for(int i = 0; i < NewItem.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = NewItem.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String description = c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);
                    int price = c.getInt(TAG_PRICE);

                    // Adding value HashMap key => value
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
                    map.put(TAG_PRICE, Integer.toString(price));
                    newItemlist.add(map);
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listupdate);
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(UpdateFromSite.this, newItemlist,
                            R.layout.updateapprow,
                            new String[] { TAG_NAME,TAG_DESCRIPTION, TAG_PRICE }, new int[] {
                            R.id.nameNewItem,R.id.descriptionNewItem, R.id.priceNewItem});
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"network problem",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    }
```

error:(logCat)

```
12-12 20:43:26.292: WARN/System.err(1069): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused
12-12 20:43:26.292: WARN/System.err(1069): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
12-12 20:43:26.302: WARN/System.err(1069): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-12 20:43:26.302: WARN/System.err(1069): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-12 20:43:26.302: WARN/System.err(1069): at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
12-12 20:43:26.302: WARN/System.err(1069): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-12 20:43:26.302: WARN/System.err(1069): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-12 20:43:26.312: WARN/System.err(1069): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-12 20:43:26.312: WARN/System.err(1069): at com.example.easyshopping.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:31)
12-12 20:43:26.312: WARN/System.err(1069): at com.example.easyshopping.UpdateFromSite$JSONParse.doInBackground(UpdateFromSite.java:89)
12-12 20:43:26.312: WARN/System.err(1069): at com.example.easyshopping.UpdateFromSite$JSONParse.doInBackground(UpdateFromSite.java:65)
12-12 20:43:26.312: WARN/System.err(1069): at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-12 20:43:26.312: WARN/System.err(1069): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
12-12 20:43:26.312: WARN/System.err(1069): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
12-12 20:43:26.312: WARN/System.err(1069): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
12-12 20:43:26.332: WARN/System.err(1069): at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
12-12 20:43:26.332: WARN/System.err(1069): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
12-12 20:43:26.345: WARN/System.err(1069): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: /127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused
12-12 20:43:26.352: WARN/System.err(1069): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
12-12 20:43:26.352: WARN/System.err(1069): at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
12-12 20:43:26.352: WARN/System.err(1069): at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
12-12 20:43:26.352: WARN/System.err(1069): at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
12-12 20:43:26.352: WARN/System.err(1069): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
12-12 20:43:26.352: WARN/System.err(1069): ... 15 more
12-12 20:43:26.364: ERROR/Buffer Error(1069): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 20:43:26.364: ERROR/JSON Parser(1069): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
12-12 20:43:26.502: WARN/InputManagerService(77): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4089e480
```

myJsonFile:

```
{"NewItem:":[{"name":"Roast Ground Coffee","description":"Folgers Medium Classic Roast Ground Coffee 339 oz","price":8},{"name":"Seattle coffee","description":"Seattles Best Coffee Level 3 Whole Bean 12oz","price":10},{"name":"Medium Roast Bean Coffee","description":"Dunkin Donuts Original Blend Medium Roast Whole Bean Coffee 12 oz","price":6},{"name":"Espresso coffee","description":"Starbucks Dark Espresso Roast Whole Bean Coffee 12 oz","price":12},
{"name":"China Green Tea","description":"Tazo China Green Tips Tea 20 filterbags","price":8},{"name":"China Organic Green","description":"Uncle Lees Legends of China Organic Green Tea 100 Tea Bags","price":15},{"name":"Black Tea","description":"Tazo Earl Grey Black Tea 20 count","price":10},{"name":"Chai Spiced Black Tea","description":"Tazo Decaf Chai Spiced Black Tea Latte Concentrate 32 oz","price":5},
{"name":"Passion Tea","description":"Tazo Iced Passion Tea 6ct","price":11},{"name":"Peach Iced Tea","description":"Lipton Diet Peach Iced Tea Mix 2.9 oz","price":12}]}
```

Comment: `/127.0.0.1:80 - Connection refused` means probably that either your backend isn't running (at least not on port 80) or firewall blocked port 80. Also, are you sure your Android up is running on localhost? If you're using real device, localhost is the device itself. If you're using emulator, try using `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740381/getting-a-jsonexception-end-of-input-at-character-0

Comment: @Victor - yeah, probably, but the real question here is why he's getting and empty response.

Comment: @kamituel, i am using emulator. let me try 10.0.2.2

Comment: Have you set internet permission in your manifest.xml?

Comment: use static ip instead of the localhost