# Android java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I got following error. java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null while get json file from server.I googled but cant find any solution for this. I am using wamp server, mysql and php to connect to my database, however when I try to register I get the below error.

I have highlighted both of error on line 189 and 232 which are in block quotes. could you please help me with what is wrong with these lines.

Error Log

```
    -04 19:41:08.572    2414-2481/com.brad.visor E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
07-04 19:41:08.572    2414-2481/com.brad.visor E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
07-04 19:41:08.602    2414-2414/com.brad.visor E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.brad.visor, PID: 2414
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.brad.visor.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:232)
            at com.brad.visor.Register$ProcessRegister.onPostExecute(Register.java:189)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Register.java File

```
public class Register extends Activity {


    /**
     *  JSON Response node names.
     **/


    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

    /**
     * Defining layout items.
     **/

    EditText inputFirstName;
    EditText inputLastName;
    EditText inputUsername;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    Button btnRegister;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;


    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        /**
         * Defining all layout items
         **/
        inputFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        inputLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);



/**
 * Button which Switches back to the login screen on clicked
                **/

                Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bktologin);
                login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Login.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                finish();
            }

        });

        /**
         * Register Button click event.
         * A Toast is set to alert when the fields are empty.
         * Another toast is set to alert Username must be 5 characters.
         **/

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (  ( !inputUsername.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputPassword.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputFirstName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputLastName.getText().toString().equals("")) && ( !inputEmail.getText().toString().equals("")) )
                {
                    if ( inputUsername.getText().toString().length() > 4 ){
                        NetAsync(view);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Username should be minimum 5 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "One or more fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    /**
     * Async Task to check whether internet connection is working
     **/

    private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String,String,Boolean>
    {
        private ProgressDialog nDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args){


/**
 * Gets current device state and checks for working internet connection by trying Google.
 **/
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                    HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                    urlc.connect();
                    if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return false;

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){

            if(th == true){
                nDialog.dismiss();
                new ProcessRegister().execute();
            }
            else{
                nDialog.dismiss();
                registerErrorMsg.setText("Error in Network Connection");
            }
        }
    }
```

> ```
>         private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> { // Error Here
> ```

```
        /**
         * Defining Process dialog
         **/
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        String email,password,fname,lname,uname;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
            inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pword);
            fname = inputFirstName.getText().toString();
            lname = inputLastName.getText().toString();
            email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            uname= inputUsername.getText().toString();
            password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(fname, lname, email, uname, password);

            return json;


        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            /**
             * Checks for success message.
             **/
            try {
```

> if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { //Error here

```
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);

                    String red = json.getString(KEY_ERROR);

                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        pDialog.setTitle("Getting Data");
                        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Info");

                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Successfully Registered");


                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        /**
                         * Removes all the previous data in the SQlite database
                         **/

                        UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                        logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_FIRSTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_LASTNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),json_user.getString(KEY_USERNAME),json_user.getString(KEY_UID),json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));
                        /**
                         * Stores registered data in SQlite Database
                         * Launch Registered screen
                         **/

                        Intent registered = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Registered.class);

                        /**
                         * Close all views before launching Registered screen
                         **/
                        registered.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(registered);


                        finish();
                    }

                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==2){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("User already exists");
                    }
                    else if (Integer.parseInt(red) ==3){
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Invalid Email id");
                    }

                }


                else{
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


            }
        }}
    public void NetAsync(View view){
        new NetCheck().execute();
    }}
```

Manifest.java File

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.brad.visor" >

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Login">
        </activity>
        <activity

            android:name=".Register">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Registered">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PasswordReset">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChangePassword">
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Allow to connect with internet and to know the current network state-->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


</manifest>
```

Userfunction.java Code

```
public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    //URL of the PHP API
    private static String loginURL =    "http://192.168.0.3:8080/bradvisor_login_api/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://192.168.0.3:8080/bradvisor_login_api/";
    private static String forpassURL =  "http://192.168.0.3:8080/bradvisor_login_api/";
    private static String chgpassURL =  "http://192.168.0.3:8080/bradvisor_login_api/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";
    private static String forpass_tag = "forpass";
    private static String chgpass_tag = "chgpass";


    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * Function to Login
     **/

    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function to change password
     **/

    public JSONObject chgPass(String newpas, String email){
        List params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", chgpass_tag));

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("newpas", newpas));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(chgpassURL, params);
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function to reset the password
     **/

    public JSONObject forPass(String forgotpassword){
        List params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", forpass_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("forgotpassword", forgotpassword));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(forpassURL, params);
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function to  Register
     **/
    public JSONObject registerUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String password){
        // Building Parameters
        List params = new ArrayList();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", uname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL,params);
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Function to logout user
     * Resets the temporary data stored in SQLite Database
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }

}
```

JsonPraser.java File

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
```

Comment: Possibly relevant threads: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8214974/535871 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740381/getting-a-jsonexception-end-of-input-at-character-0

Comment: Both of them are unhelpful, could you please help me I got the code from http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/08/develop-android-login-registration-with-php-mysql.html and you can downloald the source file to look at the code, however mine is not working for some reason could you please help.

Comment: I'm going to tell you the same thing that those posts say: most likely there's a problem with the JSON coming back from the server (in particular, the response appears to be empty).That's causing the `JSONException` which is then causing the `NullPointerException` (and possibly other problems). The empty response problem may be caused by a problem on the server side or in how you are setting up the request.

Comment: I dont think that their is any problems with the database connection, however could you please rewrite or help as those post are all not useful.

Comment: The best way to diagnose this is to set a breakpoint inside `getJSONFromUrl` on the line that calls `httpClient.execute(httpPost)`. Then examine the contents of the `httpPost` entity and determine exactly what's being sent to the server in the request. (You could also insert a line `((UrlEncodedFormEntity) httpPost.getEntity).writeTo(System.out);` to see in logcat what's being sent.) If all looks good, then test whether you are indeed receiving the expected response. (I did notice a bug: your reading loop should be appending `line + "\n"`, not `line + "n"`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can call Async Task from within another Async Task. Problem is in RegisteredUser Function.

Comment: the solution to your problem is, chek your Network Connectivity, when you perform ClickEvent on Button, and after parsing all your data, then call new ProcessRegister().execute();

Comment: Could you please advise or rewrite the code for me

Comment: My internet connection is strong and its connected to my database which I am using wamp server, when I try to register users I get the above errors. could you please advise.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that an `AsyncTask` cannot initiate another `AsyncTask`? That's simply wrong.

Comment: its not matter of Strong Internet Connectivity, its matter of Rules, You are calling Async Task from within another, thats problem.

Comment: Could you please help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `doInBackground` is returning `null`. Thus, when `onPostExecute` runs, the argument `json` is `null`. To avoid an exception, test whether `json` is `null` before proceeding with the rest of the logic. You'll probably have to find out why `userFunction.registerUser(...)` is returning `null` to truly fix the problem.

Comment: Ted How do I test weather json is null, I am new too android studio. I normally use eclipse.

Comment: With a simple `if (json == null) { ... }` statement. The body of the `if` might log an error message and return, or do something else. The important thing is to avoid executing `json.getString()` whenever `json` is `null`.

Comment: could you edit the code for me

Comment: @james - Come on. You can figure this little bit out yourself. Just insert something like this at the very beginning of `onPostExecute`: `if (json == null) { Log.e("ProcessRegister", "json was null!"); return; }`. You might also want to throw up a `Toast` until you figure out the real problem.

Comment: Ted once I have added this into the code I am now getting the same error plus one more error 07-05 19:12:02.771    2394-2436/com.brad.visor E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
07-05 19:12:02.771    2394-2436/com.brad.visor E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
07-05 19:12:02.815    2394-2394/com.brad.visor E/ProcessRegister﹕ json was null!

Comment: @james - Is the exception being thrown from `doInBackground`? If so, that's where you need to focus your efforts.

Comment: Yes it is. Could please help me to fix my problem, I have been working on this for few weeks now and still cant find an answer or solution.

Comment: @james - Please post the entire stack trace. You haven't posted any code that involves a variable named `lock` and the stack trace you posted was for the `NullPointerException` that was a secondary effect of the real problem (which seems to be a JSON parsing problem). It would also help if you posted the JSON text that your code is trying to parse.

Comment: I  have updated the error log.

Answer (score 0):

in userFunction.registerUser ( as your refisterUser function returned a JsonObject), better to check the returned String before converting it to Json as

add a check as

```
if(returnedString == null || returnedString == "null") { return; }
```

Comment: also share code userFunction.registerUser(...) of function, problem is in this function.

Comment: When adding this in I am getting an error, could you please rewrite the code for me with the added part as II am getting error it is not recognising returnedstring

Comment: share userFunction.registerUser(...) code

Comment: returnedString is the response that you read, you may be using another variable for this, I just wrote you, so that you can get an idea, the real problem is in your registerUser() function,

Comment: I have added my userfuction.java and Jsonparser.java file. These two are library files.

Comment: In JsonParser.Java

json = sb.toString();

if(json == null || json.equal("null")
{
  return;
}

log json and check what json is returning,

Comment: add my if condition after this line
json = sb.toString(); in file JsonParser.java

as
Log.i("TESTJSON",json);
if(json == null || json.equal("null") 
{ 
return;
 }

after running, search TESTJSON in LogCat and send the value. Thanks

Comment: I am getting error can you please rewrite this bit of the code for me.

Comment: Could you please hep