# Get user's photo from json of instagram in android

Tags: android, json, exception, instagram

I used this link
**URL 1**: https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/+"user_instagram_id"+/media/recent/?access_token=+"user_instagram_acess_token";

here **"user_instagram_id"** is **user id** and **"user_instagram_acess_token"** is **acess token of instagram** which I get during integration of json,

When I use **URL 1** the url formed is correct as it gives correct result in json, I also checked it from online jsonviewer, but when i retrive the Json, it gives error
 **Json Exception**: **End of input at character 0 of**

- There is no problem with json as i checked it from **http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/**
- There is no problem in the method as when i change the url it gives right response

  So Can anyone please tell me why this error comes, Where is the exactly problem.
                                                                 Thanks in advance...

Comment: `End of input at character 0` means that your json response is empty.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202048/org-json-json-exception-end-of-input-at-character-0

Comment: I have noticed one thing more acess token which I got from instagram side containing dot. Like  **#########.########.######** May this problem comes because of this dot.? And Which special character I used  for this dot.